# Errors in building Qt Static 5.3.2

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake, qmake

So I am attempting to build Qt  Static 5.3.2.  The build is being automated by a windowspowershell script I found at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC.   I am getting errors I don't fully understand, because I have verified the existence of the following files in the source, and I have checked to see if they have been copied to the correct directory and they are there.

```
    copy /y C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2\qtbase\examples\widgets\widgets.pro    C:\Qt\Static\5.3.2\examp
    les\widgets
            1 file(s) copied.
    mingw32-make[3]: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
    mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2/qtbase/examples/widgets'
    Makefile:415: recipe for target 'sub-widgets-install_subtargets' failed
    mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-widgets-install_subtargets] Error 2

copy /y C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2\qtbase\examples\README C:\Qt\Static\5.3.2\examples
        1 file(s) copied.
mingw32-make[2]: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2/qtbase/examples'
Makefile:78: recipe for target 'sub-examples-install_subtargets' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-examples-install_subtargets] Error 2

xcopy /s /q /y /i C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2\qtbase\doc\global C:\Qt\Static\5.3.2\doc\global
59 File(s) copied
mingw32-make[1]: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.2/qtbase'
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-install_subtargets' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-install_subtargets] Error 2
mingw32-make: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
```

Comment: Don't you get any errors before that ?

Comment: @SergioMartins - No, I CTRL-F Errors and those were the three I found.

Comment: @law Did you find a solution for this? I've just hit the same problem with 5.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to output powershell script output (.\windows-build-qt-static.ps1 > out.txt) and find strings with error information to get more understanding.

I've had the same final error and when I've inspected script output, I've found out that WATCOM headers were used in the process of compilation.

```
...
Environment:
    INCLUDE=
      C:\WATCOM\H
      C:\WATCOM\H\NT
      C:\WATCOM\H\NT\DIRECTX
      C:\WATCOM\H\NT\DDK
...
```

The source of the problem was INCLUDE environment variable that was set to WATCOM compiler headers

```
INCLUDE

C:\WATCOM\H;C:\WATCOM\H\NT;C:\WATCOM\H\NT\DIRECTX;C:\WATCOM\H\NT\DDK
```

I've modified it to point to MinGw headers

```
INCLUDE

C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include;C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\mingw482_32\include
```

This solved problem for me.

This may be not your error, but the point is, you should look at script output.

Answer (score -1):

May be you don't installed ActivePerl or Python. Try it. It helped me.